# Can't connect function imported outside of class qt

Tags: python, qt, class, python-import

I have a large function(s) (600+ lines) that I wan't to remove from my main code for readability, however, I am unable to reference the function within my main window class. If I move the import statement to inside the class it works seamlessly, but I plan on using it elsewhere so don't want to import it multiple times. Is there a simple way to reference the imported function from within the window?

```
import sys
import cv2
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui
import mainWindowUI
from videoFunctions import videoFeed

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, mainWindowUI.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setup_camera()

    def setup_camera(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)      
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.videoFeed)
        self.timer.start(30)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Traceback:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 790, in runfile
  execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:\WinPython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 77, in execfile
  exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Scanner.py", line 42, in <module>
form = MainWindow()
File "C:/Scanner.py", line 17, in __init__
self.setup_camera()
File "C:/Scanner.py", line 37, in setup_camera
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.videoFeed)
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'videoFeed'
```

Comment: No function should be 600 lines. Even 60 is pushing it.

Comment: The function in question is actually substantially less (~100 lines), there are just a half dozen of them (it was a gross oversimplification). Bottom line is I have a large chunk of code I wan't to move to a separate script and can't figure out how to do so while keeping the imports at the top of the file

Comment: You're referring to the function as if it was a method, which it isn't (because you've taken it out of the class). Does it need to be a method - ie does it make any reference to other data in that class?

Comment: ahhh, yes. It needs to be a method (it interacts with UI elements), I wasn't super clear on the distinction between the two but think I have it figured out now. I assume the best solution is to just define the method in the main script and try and rewrite as much as possible as importable functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility might be to put these methods into a separate class which you use as a mixin in your main class:

```
class VideoFeedMixin(object):
    def videoFeed(self):
        ...
```

and then:

```
from videoFunctions import VideoFeedMixin

class MainWindow(VideoFeedMixin, QtGui.QMainWindow, mainWindowUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    ...
```

Now `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.videoFeed)` will work just as before.